# Can I change device node with udev rules?

Tags: udev

In the recent udev(7) manpage (Fedora 22, systemd version 219), it seems that renaming a device node by udev using `NAME` key has been prohibited:

```
NAME
   The name to use for a network interface. See systemd.link(5) for a higher-level mechanism for setting
   the interface name. The name of a device node cannot be changed by udev, only additional symlinks can be
       created.
```

However, the first rule in `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/10-dm.rules` looks very much like a renaming operation:

```
KERNEL=="device-mapper", NAME="mapper/control"
```

And by checking the existence of `/dev/mapper/control` you see the renaming operation succeeded.

Curiously, however I failed to create my custom udev rule to rename my usb disk from `/dev/sdb` to `/dev/whatever`. So I thought the manual was right about the renaming restriction.

So I'm really confused now, as the builtin device mapper rule seems working pretty well while the manpage and my custom rule tells me it should not.

What is the real situation? Can udev `NAME` rename device node or not?